# Passing as a variable the individual columns of individual matrices in a list of matrices

Tags: arrays, r, list, for-loop, matrix

I want to pass columns in various matrices to a for loop.

If my two matrices had the same number of columns, I might do something like this:

```
mat1 = matrix(rep(1:25), 5,5)
mat2 = matrix(rep(26:50), 5,5)
array.mat = array(c(mat1,mat2), dim=c(5,5,2))
mat1.ncol = ncol(mat1)
mat2.ncol = ncol(mat2)
mat.ncol = c(mat1.ncol, mat2.ncol)
mat.ncol
array.mat
for (dimi in 1:2){
  dim.col = mat.ncol[dimi]
    for (coli in 1:dim.col){
      st = shapiro.test(array.mat[,coli,dimi])$p.value
        if(st > .001){
          array.mat[,coli,dimi] = log(array.mat[,coli,dimi])
}}}
```

But, my data don't have the same number of columns, so I'd like to use a list of matrices instead.

```
mat1 = matrix(rep(1:10), 5,2)
mat2 = matrix(rep(26:50), 5,5)
list.mat=list(a=mat1, b=mat2)
list.mat
```

But I can't figure out how I'd pass the columns of the matrices?

```
list.mat$a[1:5]
```

gives the first column of the first matrix, but how would you pass $a and [startindex:endindex] in a loop? All the other answers I see tend to pass the ith element (e.g., column) of *both* matrices. I need to keep the two matrices (a and b) separate for later computations, but I want them together (the list of the two matrices) for these types of loops.
Once again, I'm probably just thinking about this incorrectly. Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use numeric indices? e.g., matrix 1, column 1: `list.mat[[1]][,1]`

In a loop:

```
for (m in 1:2) {
  for (i in 1:ncol(list.mat[[m]])) {
    cat('Here is matrix', m, ', columnn', i, '\n')
    print(list.mat[[m]][,i])
  }
}
```

result:

```
Here is matrix 1 , columnn 1 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Here is matrix 1 , columnn 2 
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
Here is matrix 2 , columnn 1 
[1] 26 27 28 29 30
Here is matrix 2 , columnn 2 
[1] 31 32 33 34 35
Here is matrix 2 , columnn 3 
[1] 36 37 38 39 40
Here is matrix 2 , columnn 4 
[1] 41 42 43 44 45
Here is matrix 2 , columnn 5 
[1] 46 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: Oy! Thank you. Simple answer. I must have tried every other possible combo of syntax and kept getting incorrect number of dim errors; couldn't find this answer in 3 texts or in many a search on the web. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! List indexing is a bit weird. `my_list[1]` is a list of length 1. `my_list[[1]]` is whatever is in list position 1.